# Correct connection string for VB.NET WinForms application connecting to local SQL Server db

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, connection-string

I am building a VB.NET WinForms application in VS2013. The program is using a SQL Server 2012 ("Full" version of SQL Server - NOT SQL Express) database that is local to the deployed application - both on the development computer and the computer (the only computer) the program will be used on.

In the program, when the user clicks a button, a sql script - an sql file on the computer - needs to execute.

Depending on the type of connection string I try, I am getting different errors and I'm not sure which connection string to use.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnLoadMasterData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadMasterData.Click
    Dim connString As String = "Server=DHSNET\[dbuser];Database=hours_analysis;User Id=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD]"
    'Dim connString As String = "Server=DHSNET\[dbuser];Database=hours_analysis;Integrated Security=True"
    'Dim connString As String = "Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=C:\[PATHTOFILE]\hours_analysis.mdf"
    'Dim connString As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\[PATHTOFILE]\hours_analysis.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

    Dim file As New FileInfo("C:\HL_Time_Entry_Reporting\SQL Scripts\stage_employee_hours_load.sql")
    Dim sqlText As String = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd()

    ExecuteCommand(sqlText, connString)
End Sub

Private Sub ExecuteCommand(queryString As String, connectionString As String)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        command.Connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

As you can see, I've tried several types of connections. The fourth one is what VS2013 set up to connect to the database for the datagridviews in the application, which load and work fine.

I got the other three connection strings from the [ConnectionStrings.com "SQL Server 2012 connection strings" page](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/).

When I use the first and second connection strings there is a pause of about five seconds and then a `SqlException` error occurs on the `Connection.Open()` line, saying

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

When I use either of the connection strings for the `.mdf` file I get a `SqlException` error saying

> Database 'hours_analysis' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

(The path to the file is correct)

What connection string to I need to use?

Comment: Are you using SQLExpress? I use a local server with Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS as my connection string.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @Mark - I linked to that page in my question...

Comment: @Tim, No, I'm using the "Full" version of SQL Server - I'll clarify that in my question.

Comment: The .\ is a shortcut for localhost - have you tried that? (It should work as well)

Comment: "Server=DHSNET;Database=hours_analysis;User Id=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD]" Assuming: _DHSNET_ is the name of your computer, the database _hours_analys_ exists on the local instance, you have enabled the _Sql Server Authentication_ and a user with the password provided exists on the local database

Comment: @Steve, when I open SSMS on my computer I can use Windows (I always use Win Auth) or SQL Server Auth. And enter a period for the Server name. As for a user on the local db, I'm not sure - I'm guessing not - this is all an internal project, so no security has been set up in the SQL Server (my machine and deployment machine) or on the db itself.

Comment: You could use the same info that you have on your SSMS login screen then. The _Server_ part is the login mask Server Name, the _User ID_ and _Password_ could be removed if you use Integrated Security and replace by  _Integrated Security=True;_

Comment: @Steve - GOT IT! :) For the record, I used my computer name for the server. DHSNET is the network domain that I log into at work. So this is what worked for me: Dim connString As String = "Server=[LOCALCOMPUTERNAME];Database=hours_analysis;Integrated Security=True"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that's looking for help on this, here's what I have in my App.config file:

```
<add name="[APPLICATIONNAME].My.MySettings.LocalDevServerConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=[YOURCOMPUTERNAME];Initial Catalog=[DBYOUWANTTOCONNECTOT];Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```